# How to get Average from AvgAggregationBuilder elastic search for spesific keys

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I'm am trying to get results from [Elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-aggs.html) with spesic keys
example:

> average salary, by city, gender

so i check at [metrics_aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_metrics_aggregations.html)

and I was able

```
AvgAggregationBuilder totalDuration = AggregationBuilders.avg("salaryAvg").field("salary");
```

it did return the most high level - average salary without specific fields

So I tried using `subAggregation`

```
AvgAggregationBuilder totalDuration =     AggregationBuilders
            .avg("salaryAvg").field("salary")
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("city").field("gender"));
```

but i got below error

> Server Error. 21525\nElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch
>   exception [type=aggregation_initialization_exception,
>   reason=Aggregator [salaryAvg] of type [avg] cannot accept
>   sub-aggregations]]\n\tat
>   org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXConten

how can I query it with elastic search
what I want is something quite similar to SQL - group by

each row of my elastic response data seems like that:

```
widgetResponse.getHits().getHits()[0].getSourceAsMap().get("attributes")


{HashMap$Node@53898} "city" -> "new York"
{HashMap$Node@53899} "pageId" -> "123"
{HashMap$Node@53900} "salary" -> "45765"
{HashMap$Node@53900} "gender" -> "female"
{HashMap$Node@53901} "userId" -> "324"
{HashMap$Node@53902} "accountId" -> "456"


widgetResponse.getHits().getHits()[1].getSourceAsMap().get("attributes")


{HashMap$Node@53898} "city" -> "new Jersy"
{HashMap$Node@53899} "pageId" -> "123"
{HashMap$Node@53899} "salary" -> "77777"
{HashMap$Node@53900} "gender" -> "female"
{HashMap$Node@53901} "userId" -> "334"
{HashMap$Node@53902} "accountId" -> "999"
```

How can I support it using Elastic search JAVA API?

I tried also

running it:

```
        AvgAggregationBuilder totalDuration0 = AggregationBuilders.avg(TOTAL_DURATION_AVG).field(TOTAL_DURATION);
    TermsAggregationBuilder totalDuration = AggregationBuilders.terms(TOTAL_DURATION_AVG)
            .field(ATTRIBUTES_WIDGET_ID).subAggregation(totalDuration0);
```

I got this response

there's seems to have a different average and how much rows
for each - row in this list
but I have no idea which "key" is pointing to
seems like a byte array

but it doesn't match to the actual key I have
also [key] seems to be duplicated with a different average
so what am I missing here. ?

[image]

Comment: can you please share  your index mapping and some sample documents

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja thanks for mentioning it, added it to the question

Comment: I don't see the mapping and sample documents :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get avg by a single field, but not more than one field

```
    final AvgAggregationBuilder totalDuration = AggregationBuilders.avg(avgSalary).field(SALARY_AVG);
    final TermsAggregationBuilder totalDurationByWidgetId = AggregationBuilders.terms(SALARY_AVG)
            .field(GENDER).subAggregation(avgSalary);
```